# Multiple colors in one line in console application

Tags: c#, colors

I'm trying to get to this result of colors in the console app:

[image]

But this is my result right now:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] str = new string[] 
    {
        " ________                     __      ",
        "/        |                   /  |     ",
        "$$$$$$$$/______    _______  _$$ |_    ",
        "   $$ | /      \\  /       |/ $$   |  ",
        "   $$ |/$$$$$$  |/$$$$$$$/ $$$$$$/    ",
        "   $$ |$$    $$ |$$      \\   $$ | __ ",
        "   $$ |$$$$$$$$/  $$$$$$  |  $$ |/  | ",
        "   $$ |$$       |/     $$/   $$  $$/  ",
        "   $$/  $$$$$$$/ $$$$$$$/     $$$$/   "
    };

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < str[i].Length; j++)
        {
            if (i >= 4 && i < 7 && j > 3 && j < 5)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;   
            }   

            Console.Write(str[i][j]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

How can I get multiple colors per line on a console application ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I don't think you can do it in a loop like that. You can use combinations of `Console.ForegroundColor`, `Console.Write` (and possibly `Console.SetCursorPosition`) to write the characters you want in different colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is like this:

```
            var index = 3;
            foreach (var item in str)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
                {

                    Console.Write(item[i]);

                    Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)index;
                    index++;
                    if (index == 15)
                        index = 3;
                    if (i == item.Length - 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I used colors starting with 3 to avoid black color; 
[image]

Comment: Wow! beautiful!!

Answer (score 4):

You need to:

1. define the color you want to use
2. output something to the console

[image]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)).Cast<ConsoleColor>().ToArray();

            foreach (var color in colors)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = color;

                Console.Write("ABC");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Or**

You can take your console coloring to the next level, I have published a free and open source wrapper around the new console features in Windows 10, namely 24-bit color :)

[image]

Sources and NuGet package:

https://github.com/aybe/TrueColorConsole

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TrueColorConsole/

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you could do is write a helper method that will write an array of strings to the console starting at a particular position with a particular color:

```
private static void WriteColoredLines(string[] lines, Point start, ConsoleColor color)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;

    for (int row = 0; row < lines.Length; row++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(start.X, start.Y + row);
        Console.Write(lines[row]);
    }
}
```

Then you could call this method with the different shapes you want to write, along with the starting position and color, for example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    string[] topOfT =
    {
        " ________ ",
        "/        |",
        "$$$$$$$$/",
        "   $$ |",
        "   $$ |",
    };

    string[] bottomOfT =
    {
        "   $$ |",
        "   $$ |",
        "   $$ |",
        "   $$/",
    };

    string[] letterE =
    {
        "  ______",
        " /      \\",
        "/$$$$$$  |",
        "$$    $$ |",
        "$$$$$$$$/",
        "$$       |",
        " $$$$$$$/",
    };

    string[] lettersSandT =
    {
        "              __",
        "             /  |",
        "  _______   _$$ |_    ",
        " /       | / $$   |  ",
        "/$$$$$$$/  $$$$$$/    ",
        "$$      \\    $$ | __ ",
        "  $$$$$$ |   $$ |/  | ",
        "/      $$/   $$  $$/  ",
        "$$$$$$$/     $$$$/   "
    };

    WriteColoredLines(topOfT, new Point(0, 0), ConsoleColor.Green);
    WriteColoredLines(bottomOfT, new Point(0, 5), ConsoleColor.Blue);
    WriteColoredLines(letterE, new Point(9, 2), ConsoleColor.Blue);
    WriteColoredLines(lettersSandT, new Point(20, 0), ConsoleColor.Gray);

    Console.Write("\n\n\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]